# PHP IMAP fetch X-GM-THRID

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I want to get the X-GM-THRID from a message with the standard PHP IMAP functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php).

I can't find how to get this information. I know that it exists (https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#access_to_the_gmail_thread_id_x-gm-thrid) and found how to do it in other languages. But I can't find a PHP example.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can with that library.  The PHP functions are not flexible.  You would have to change and recompile the module.

Comment: What library could get that value?

Comment: If you leave PHP, there are much more flexible libraries for perl, python, java....